# angular8.0 dynamic import not support webpack magic comments

Tags: angular, webpack, angular8

I upgrade my angular7 to angular8, I noticed my webpack version downgrade from 4.33.0 to 4.30.0. angular8 support dynamic importing, so I want to use webpack "magic comments" to customize my angular module chunk name, but it is not working.

```
{
   path: "published",
   loadChildren: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "DashboardPublished" */ './dashboard-published/dashboard-published.module').then(m => m.DashboardPublishedModule)},
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working when you build for development mode only. Make sure to set the flag `namedChunks` in `Angular.json` to `true` before building.

build:
[image: build]

For production build it doesn't work.

prod:
[image: prod]